# XML Deserialization Permissions Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-6, xml-serialization, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to use VS 2008 t publish a website to a virtual on my computer. The website runs just fine in VS2008 while debugging, but when I publish it, I'm getting the following error.

> Access to the path 'C:\dummy.xml' is
>   denied.  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path 'C:\dummy.xml' is
>   denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6) that is
>   used if the application is not
>   impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity
>   will be the anonymous user (typically
>   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
>   right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the
>   Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
>   appropriate user or group. Highlight
>   the ASP.NET account, and check the
>   boxes for the desired access.

I'm deserializing an XML file into a class built up by xsd.exe. The file and directory have the same permissions, and I can get to the xml file from a web browser.  The service account being used to run / access the website (directory security settings in IIS) has full control permissions on the folder and the xml file.

I'm running Server 2003 R2 with IIS 6.

Any thoughts on how to correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a filemon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to monitor 'C:\dummy.xml'. When you'll get the error check which Windows user is trying to access the file.

Comment: That worked like a charm. It turns out that the IIS worker process (IIS_WPG) was trying to open the file with write access, and it only had read access.